# Unread messages in non-muted participating events

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Organizer (`event.user`) should also have an `attendance` (with muted true/false).

Here are the simplified models from `db/schema.rb`:

```rb
  create_table "attendances" do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "event_id"
    t.boolean "muted"
  end

  create_table "events" do

  create_table "message_reads" do |t|
    t.bigint "message_id"
    t.bigint "user_id"
  end

  create_table "messages" do |t|
    t.string "from_type"
    t.bigint "from_id"
    t.string "to_type"
    t.bigint "to_id"
    t.text "content"
  end

  create_table "users" do |t|
    t.string "email"
  end
```

How could I know which messages are not read for an user? and which events that have unread messages? (in the same query with a `GROUP BY` it would be awesome)

knowing that if the sender is the user the message is read and that there needs to be an attendance that is not muted

thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "event have unread messages"? Does an event have messages as the "to" or "from"? If not, how are events and messages connected?

Comment: I'm confused by "knowing that if the sender is the user the message is read" - are you saying that the messages we care about for a user are "Message.where(to: user)"?

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret "there needs to be an attendance that is not muted". How do messages connect to an event or attendance? Does event have a message_id or message have an event-id? Happy to update my answer once I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about some of the additional requirements, but here's an attempt at unread messages for a user assuming the following activerecord setup.

```
# assuming your models look something like this...
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :received_messages, as: :to
  has_many :sent_messages, as: :from
  has_many :message_reads
end
class Messages < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :to, polymorphic: true
  has_many :message_reads
end

# unread messages
@unread_messages = @user.received_messages.left_outer_joins(:message_reads).where(message_reads: {id: nil})
```

This uses the [left_outer_joins](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_joins) method from Rails 5.0. In earlier versions of Rails you can use the [left-join plugin](https://github.com/diego-aslz/left_join).

Not sure how an event connects to a message - does an event have a `message_id` or vise versa?